# C2DM Push chat application

Tags: java, android, chat, android-c2dm

Currenlty I am trying to develop a simple chat application for Android. I want to create something that works like WhatsApp. Because it should be realtime, I think C2DM is the best way to send a notification when a user sends a message to another user.

Because I have read that C2DM is build for noticiations only, and not for messages I have to find a way to deliver those messages to that other contact.

Now, I have a application server, that can send C2DM notifications. But what's the best and the most energy saving way to send and receive the 'textmessages'?

I have read about polling, but it's not that energy saving I think. I have read something about 'XMPP', but how can I combine that with C2DM?

Comment: Have you thought about costs of C2DM ??

Comment: If you mean the energy costs? Yes, because there already a open C2DM connection, you can use this connection. I have also seen different presentations where the result is that C2DM is the most energy saving way to push notificatoins.

Comment: If we have to use polling
Check for freshness on the server-side
If-Modified-Since =>304 if nothing's new
Poll as infrequently as possible
Idle power draw ~ 5-8 mA
But in a poll, network draws 115-200 mA
~ 0.5 mAh per short poll (radio stays on for awhile)
~ 144 mAh/day with 5 min polling frequency
~ 10% of the battery!
~ 48 mAh/day with 15 min polling frequency

Answer (score 0):

1. User A sends message to User B, that is, it sends a message to your application server.
2. You app server receives a message from A to B. It sends a C2DM notification to B telling that there is new data.
3. User B receives the C2DM notification of new data, connects to your app server and retrieves the message from User A.

This mechanism only pushes data, there is no polling.

Comment: Thanks, but what is the most energy efficient way to retrieve the message from the application server? I guess with a webrequest?

Comment: Well it's not a trivial question. This makes an http request each time the user has new data. It's surely more effective than polling. If you are asking about XMPP, I don't know. Whatsapp uses XMPP, this protocol is made for real time messaging so in overall it should fit better your needs since that's exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: Yes, WhatsApp uses XMPP if I am right. But how can I combine WhatsApp with XMPP? Because if XMPP is realtime, I don't have to use C2DM if I am right? Or do I have to check the XMPP server if there are new messages. What is the best option for this?

Comment: I can't answer this since I don't know XMPP. What I would do is take a look at the protocol and see how it looks like. I'm pretty sure XMPP defines a long lived connection like C2DM to handle pushing, so maybe there is no need to use C2DM.

Comment: But in step 1 you said: 'User A sends message to User B, that is, it sends a message to your application server'. What is the best way to send the message to the server?